# What is "app_store_keychain-db" and why doesn't my password work

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, keychain

What is the "app_store_keychain-db", or more specifically why doesn't my regular account password work for this keychain?

It contains an expired certificate that I want to remove, and it won't accept my regular password (all the other keychains accept the password and I have not changed the password on this computer yet).

Could it be created by [Fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane) - if that is the case, what is the password?

Could it be created by XCode 11?

Does anyone know?